# Statfs return strange values

Tags: c++, linux, unix

I'm currently trying to get disk space in byte en used space in byte with statfs().
I made a small function but i get really strange values.
(I'm working on a ubuntu 32bit system)

Here is the code:

```
bool
CheckDiskSpace( const CLString &devPath, ulonglong &diskSize, ulonglong &totalFreeBytes )
{
bool retVal = false;
struct statfs fs;
if( ( statfs( devPath.c_str(), &fs ) ) < 0 ) {
    printf( "Failed to stat %s: %s\n", devPath.c_str() ,strerror( errno ) );
    return false;
} else {
    diskSize = fs.f_blocks * fs.f_bsize;
    totalFreeBytes = fs.f_bfree * fs.f_bsize;
    retVal = true;
}
return retVal;
}

int main()
{
  ulonglong diskSize, totalFreeBytes;
  CheckDiskSpace( "/dev/sda5", diskSize, totalFreeBytes );
  printf( "Disk size: %llu Byte\n", diskSize );
  printf( "Free size: %llu Byte\n", totalFreeBytes );
}
```

And I get:

```
Disk size: 1798447104 Byte
Free size: 1798443008 Byte
```

I do really not understand this result because with "df" command I get:

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5            111148848  47454952  58047832  45% /
udev                   1756296         4   1756292   1% /dev
tmpfs                   705324       912    704412   1% /run
none                      5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                   1763300      1460   1761840   1% /run/shm
```

Any help is very appeciated !

PS: I have a 120 GB ssd and my partition is in Ext4.

EDIT: ulonglong is a predifined type:

```
typedef unsigned long long ulonglong;
```

Comment: why are you returning true/false if you are not even checking them?

Comment: According to `statfs(2)`, the `f_bsize` member is the "optimal transfer block size". What makes you think that's the data block size for the filesystem as it pertains to the `f_blocks` member?

Comment: That's just a sample of the full code, i'm checking them somewhere else.

Comment: @Borealid: i tried with f_frsize using statvfs, but i get the same values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the result for the tmpfs mounted on `/dev` as the `/dev/sda5` is on that filesystem. If you want to know for your root filesystem, just use `/` or any path not in `/dev` nor `/run`.

Comment: That's exactly what i thought, and i already tried that, but the result is as strange as the previous one:  Disk size: 2147270656 Byte
Free size: 795549696 Byte. And i think it's false because it gives me 1.99980163574219 gigabyte of disk space.

Comment: What do you mean as strange? If it's not the exact same value, it's probably because you are counting bytes and df prints it in 1KB block. Trying dividing by 1024.

Comment: Did you made any other modification of your code in the meantime? Because the result in your question is the exact same value printed by `df` (for `/dev` as I already said), divided by 1024... I don't think it was a coincidence.

Comment: Yes i put "/" instead of "/dev/sda5" as you suggest ! But that give me the same result as the df command divided by 1024 ...

Comment: With "/" : Disk size: 2147270656 Byte. And that is false isn't it !!?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understood your last comment. Opening `"/"` instead of `"/dev"` gives you the same result than when you were opening `"/dev/sda5"` (`1798447104`) or the result you gave in your first comment (`2147270656`) ? What I meant is that with the code you gave in your question and the result you are getting, it is totally normal as you are retrieving the `/dev` tmpfs size, not the one for your root filesystem. Are you saying that `statfs()` works correctly for `"/dev/sda5"` and not correctly for `"/"` then?

Comment: Ok so you are having a weird value only for your root filesystem then. Depending on the block size, the value might be too big to fit in the statfs structure, maybe you could try with `statfs64()` instead? I would have expected `statfs()` to return `EOVERFLOW` in this case...

Comment: Ok sorry, i didn't explain it right. When i check my partition with disk utility, i got 116 GB of capacity. Then when i run the code above with "/" the result is:  Disk size: 2147270656 Byte.

Comment: Ow that can be a possibility ! but you know, i don't get any EOVERFLOW error with the code below.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6727/discussion-between-quentin-casasnovas-and-atha)

Comment: LOOOOOL, you were right, it works perfectly with statfs64(). Thant you very much. But still, i don't understand why the system allows me to return an Incomplete value ??

Answer (score 0):

i think what you want is:

```
CheckDiskSpace( "/dev/sda5", &diskSize, &totalFreeBytes );
```

because diskSize and totalFreeBytes are not changed in CheckDiskSpace with your code

Comment: I know, that's because it's just some parts of my code. In the full code, they are changed.

Comment: @fazo they are passed as reference, it's C++.